# Services prefer to block executable files, why is that?

Tags: security, jar

I have been having a discussion with a friend of mine about executable files, more specifically .jar and .exe files.

When you download a file from your browser it usually asks for permission to store that specific file, is there a reason why that happens?

An example would be "gmail" or any other mailing service that "blocks" executable attachments supposedly because they can infect your system, if so, what's the technicalities behind that?

The following is probably a personal opinion, which is against the stackoverflow guidelines of writing proper posts, you can hover over it if you want on your own, I'd greatly appreciate it if you could confirm or deny my hypothesis on a comment reply.

> I believe that the reason behind this, blocking specific executables is because they actually run on your device when you store them. For example a (.jar) file would be executed by Java the moment you allow it to be stored on your device because Java needs to make sure it's a proper executable. To me this raises a security concern because any executable that contains malicious code would be executed at least once without you knowing (or at least understanding that you allowed it to run in the first place).

I'd love to know if there is an actual reason behind this, thank you.

[Message prompt from Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syXsa.png)

Comment: Can you show an example of browser asking for permission to **store** an executable file? I've never seen one do so. AFAIK browsers ask before saving files, but it's not related to them being executable. Well, it's not even possible to check if a file is executable without downloading it - extensions can be misleading. Windows also asks before running downloaded executables, but that's not what your question is about.

Comment: @gronostaj: Many browsers ask twice if the file is recognized as a "risky" format, or based on some other heuristics. Firefox doesn't let you select "Always do this" for executable files (other formats can be chosen to automatically open _or_ automatically be saved to ~/Downloads; but for .exe's you always get the prompt). Chrome has "This file can harm your computer" based on format and on Safe Browsing status.

Comment: @gronostaj I have included the specific prompt that happens on Google Chrome for me, look at the end of the post, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that the reason behind this, blocking specific executables is because they actually run on your device when you store them.

No. The act of storing files never executes them.

> For example a (.jar) file would be executed by Java the moment you allow it to be stored on your device because Java needs to make sure it's a proper executable

No. "Java" doesn't care at all.

> To me this raises a security concern because any executable that contains malicious code would be executed at least once without you knowing

That's a very valid concern, but the culprit here is not "storing executable files on a device", but overeager programmers that want to make life easier for "dumb" users and automatically do lots of things they shouldn't do without prompting. In particular Windows has a very bad history with respect to this.

But currently your browser does not do this, and only asks because "dumb" users tend to download executables from who-knows-where, and later execute them, so this is actually to raise awareness of this possible security problem.

Comment: So downloading a .jar file and then "allowing" it on your device (as per the chrome prompt) won't execute it without you clicking on it, doesn't the build-in java interpreter at least once run the .jar to make sure it's properly compiled ?

Comment: @tsourtzis: Why would it need to know that?

Comment: @grawity For example downloading any file don't you want to sure you have done an MD5 or SHA check ? Going by that I thought that the interpreter would do something along those lines, thanks for the clarifcation.

Comment: And what MD5 or SHA should it be compared to? One embedded in the JAR file? Then whoever tinkers with that file to make it do something bad can tinker with the MD5/SHA as well. The whole point of checking MD5/SHA signature is that those signatures **must come from some other channel**. So the likelihood that both the downloaded file and the signature are compromised at the same time is lower. And you should get the idea "the Java interpreter needs to do checking before even attempting to run the JAR" out of your head, that's not how it works.